# How to validate text box inputs in real-time

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, textbox

Its an application which asks a math problem and user inputs answer in a textbox as integers, and a button `submitbtn` verifies if its right or wrong.
I binded a keyboard key `f` to the function that runs on pressing button `submitbtn`, which works fine, but the key `f` gets added to the textbox after user's answer before it submits and gives it as a wrong answer.

Text Box

```
text_Input = StringVar
txtbox = Entry(font=('arial',20, BOLD), textvariable=text_Input)
txtbox.grid(columnspan = 2, row = 3, pady = 20)
txtbox.focus_set()
```

Submit Button

```
submitbtn = Button(text="Submit", padx=10, pady=10, command=lambda:submit(txtbox.get(), y))
```

Submit Function

```
def submit(z, y):
    global correct_answer, wrong_answer, submitbtn
    y=str(y)
    if z==y:
        correct_answer+=1
        lbl2.configure(text=correct_answer)
    else:
        wrong_answer+=1
        lbl4.configure(text=wrong_answer)
    submitbtn.config(state="disabled")
```

Binding

```
game.bind('f', lambda event: submit(txtbox.get(), y))
#"game" is the name of Tk()
#submit is the function linked to submitbtn
#This works well if I bind it to <Return> (Enter Key)
```

Actual Output:

5+8

User enters: 13

Presses 'f' to submit answer

Answer processed: 13f

1. Is there a way to process textbox inputs in real-time to make sure every character entered is an integer? If user enters anything except 0-9, I want it to note nothing in the textbox.
2. Also, I disable the `submitbtn` after it is pressed once, but pressing f repeatedly keep incrementing the `correct_answer` variable. Is there a way to bind the key to the `submitbtn` which in turn will call the function `submit`, instead of directly linking the key `f` to `submit` function?

Comment: By text box you mean `Entry` widget or `Text` widget?

Comment: @HenryYik Entry Widget. I added the textbox code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, there are two ways to do it. Either you use the `trace` method on your `StringVar`, or use `validcommand` on your entry. You can read up the details on how to use both methods [here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/interactively-validating-entry-widget-content-in-tkinter)

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# Use trace method on your StringVar

text_Input = tk.StringVar() # note that it is StringVar() with ()
txtbox = tk.Entry(font="Arial 20 bold",textvariable=text_Input)
txtbox.grid(columnspan = 2, row = 3, pady = 20)

def trace_method(*args):
    if text_Input.get().isdigit():
        pass
    else:
        text_Input.set(text_Input.get()[:-1])

text_Input.trace("w",trace_method)

# Use validatecommand attribute of entry widget

def onValidate(S):
    if S.isdigit():
        return True
    else:
        return False

vcmd = (root.register(onValidate),"%S")

txtbox2 = tk.Entry(font="Arial 20 bold",validate="key",validatecommand=vcmd)
txtbox2.grid(columnspan = 2, row = 4, pady = 20)

root.mainloop()
```

For your second question, I can't fully understand what you are trying to achieve, but if the problem lies with the binding with key f, i suppose you can simply call `game.unbind('f')` in your `submit` function.